# how to switch browser tabs using batch

Tags: batch-file, firefox, browser, microsoft-edge, sendkeys

I have created two independent batch files. Both open web browsers. One opens Firefox and the other Opens Edge. Both batches are opening multiple tabs in their respective applications. How do I write a batch to pass through the Control + Tab keys in batch at the end of my file to go back to the first tab?

Can this be done with Edge and Firefox? Can they be written the same way?

I don't need the tabs to refresh upon the switch.

I've tried this for Edge,

```
@echo off

start microsoft-edge:"https://stackoverflow.com"
start microsoft-edge:"https://google.com"

timeout 2
$wshell=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('microsoft-edge'); # Activate on EDGE browser
$wshell.SendKeys('^+{TAB}'); # CONTROL+SHIFT+TAB
```

..to no prevail. Yes, the batch starts and opens Edge and applies the two addresses to two tabs but I can not figure out how to SendKeys to the application.

Any Tips or Pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many ways to send keys combination but the combination of `^+{TAB}` seems always not work. I find a software called [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) which can achieve your goal.

You can first download the software and create a autohotkey script file named `test.ahk`, with following content:

```
send ^{TAB}
exit
```

Then run the `test.ahk` in bat file:

```
@echo off

start microsoft-edge:"https://stackoverflow.com"
start microsoft-edge:"https://google.com"

timeout 2
$wshell=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('microsoft-edge'); 
"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ahk"
```

Please notice to replace the path with your own path. I've tested it and this could be a workaround.